# Use tamil fonts in php mysql application

Tags: php, html, tamil

I would like to use tamil fonts in php mysql application? Suggest some ideas for type tamil in input fields by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); "**
Before write query add this line will solve the problem...instead special 
characters tamil letters will save...

Bes sure use char set utf8 in html header.... 
**ALL THE BEST**

Answer (score 1):

Unicode Format

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Best unicode tamil font support by following api script,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var poplo =new Array("textareaid");
ENABLED_TIWEB = "http://api.tamilsg.com/data/lookuptable.js";
var fileref = document.createElement('script');
fileref.src = "http://api.tamilsg.com/hplus.js";
document.documentElement.appendChild(fileref);
```

Thanks a lot.